# How to convert fixed length text file into CSV file

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have a text file with fixed length data.
The file contains 3 fields. The first one is 7 characters, the second is 19 characthers and the last one is 6 characters.
I wrote a batch file to convert it into a CSV file.
Due to organization restrictions i can't install any outer programs like powershell so i need it to be pure DOS commands
I wrote the following script but it seems that i missed something.
Any ideas?

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (test.txt) do (
set %MYVAR%=%%A
set mer=%MYVAR:~0,7%
set cr=%MYVAR:~7,19%
set dt=%MYVAR:~26,6%
set "y=%mer%,%cr%,%dt%"
echo %y%>> test.csv
```

Comment: Does this help?  http://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=147278.0

Comment: You are not _really_ using MS-DOS, are you? The Windows command line has nothing to do with "DOS". Btw: Powershell is installed by default in every Windows 7 if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

In batch, when using variables in a code block (that is code inside parenthesis's) you need to `enabledelayedexpansion` and use exclamation marks instead of percentage signs.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (test.txt) do (
set var=%%A
set mer=!var:~0,7!
set cr=!var:~7,19!
set dt=!var:~26,6!
set "y=!mer!,!cr!,!dt!"
echo !y!>> test.csv
)
```

Which should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're doing with this CSV file after it's converted, you might be able to interact with your fixed-width text file *as* a CSV file natively with no substring extraction or conversion.  Just create a [`Schema.ini`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) file within the same directory as your fixed-width file with the following contents:

```
[filename.txt]
ColNameHeader=False
CharacterSet=1252
Format=FixedLength
Col1=mer Text Width 7
Col2=cr Text Width 19
Col3=dt Text Width 6
```

And voila!  The MS Jet, Ace, and other text-mode drivers should now recognize your fixed width file as a CSV file with no massaging.

On a side note, if you'd like a batch utility for interacting with CSV files, [you might find this useful](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6184).